# Navigation Drawers with Action Bar Tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-navigation

I have read something that "you shouldn't use Navigation Drawers with Action Bar Tabs" (Roman Nurik at https://plus.google.com/u/0/+DavidTaSmoochibi/posts/8dWEkFcbTFX). Is there any meaningful reason of this ? So if a team decided to create a big project with Action Bar Tabs and then on the second version, they decided to put a cool slider menu on the left side with Navigation Drawer, in this case they have to re-implement all tabs by avoiding Action Bar Tab styling ??

I use them in the same project but I saw that the Action Bar Tabs are always above the Navigation Drawer.

Is there any way to use both in the way the Navigation Drawer works as it should be (over the other elements) ?

Answer (score -1):

A classic example would be Google's Play Store itself. If it has the navigation drawer then it will not have the action bar tabs and if it has action bar tabs it will not have the navigation drawer.

I think this is basically because if you click on one element of the navigation drawer, then the `Activity` has to load a `Fragment` into its `FrameLayout`. In case of action bar tabs too, the Activity has to deal with `Fragment`s.

So, even if it is possible, I wouldn't go through the hassle of implementing it.

Comment: Thats not a solution. However I've been looking for about a week and it seems that you will have to use or actionbarsherlock or TabHost. Using TabHost, you can get the NavigationDrawer in front of the tabs. Thats the only way that found to work properly withput use an external library, but the TabHost is not the new way to achive it... hope it can be a promp answer to that!